# How can I build when execution (EXE) file is being used?

Tags: c#, build

I run many instance(100+) of an App I created in c# on my PC.

The App is quite complicated, and I can run the App in several different modes BUT all Apps share a lot of fundamental code.

I would like to reBuild and run an instance of the App whilst leaving all other instance running.

But - when I "Build" I get an error telling me exe file cannot be created as it is being used by another process.

Is there anyway around this?

Please note: I DO NOT wish to copy exe to somewhere else before launching instance from there. That would just give me a similar error one step later.

Comment: As I consider, you can't override the exe file while it's running, so you need to copy exe file somewhere.

Comment: this is one reason why you need separate development and production environments. if you can't develop and test your applications without affecting other applications, then you have a fundamentally broken development/deployment process.

Comment: Agreed. BUT this stuff is only for me!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are running a microservices architecture where each microservice is run using the same monolithic code and some unique configuration. I think your solution would be to accept the fact that they are different services and split their code (likely sharing some common code in a class library) into separate executable projects.